# Google Maps Force closing

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have been trying to add a map to my application, I have followed instructions on the android developers HelloGoogleMaps tutorial but my map is just force closing when I run the maps option.  I have obtained my api key logged permissions in manifest (Internet, Maps) and logged intent.  When I look at the debugger the intent line always shows up but I have put in  test code and the intent is fine but it seems to be saying it cannot locate the class;

09-28 07:09:13.960: DEBUG/dalvikvm(308): VFY: replacing opcode 0x1c at 0x0013

09-28 07:09:14.000: DEBUG/dalvikvm(308): VFY: dead code 0x0015-001b in Lcom/ff/org/ll2;.onListItemClick (Landroid/widget/ListView;Landroid/view/View;IJ)V

09-28 07:09:29.240: INFO/ActivityManager(59): Starting activity: Intent { cmp=com.ff.org/.Bradford }

09-28 07:09:29.350: WARN/dalvikvm(308): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/ff/org/Locate; (67)

09-28 07:09:29.350: WARN/dalvikvm(308): Link of class 'Lcom/ff/org/Locate;' failed

09-28 07:09:29.350: ERROR/dalvikvm(308): Could not find class 'com.ff.org.Locate', referenced from method com.ff.org.Bradford.onListItemClick

09-28 07:09:29.350: WARN/dalvikvm(308): VFY: unable to resolve const-class 37 (Lcom/ff/org/Locate;) in Lcom/ff/org/Bradford;

09-28 07:09:29.360: DEBUG/dalvikvm(308): VFY: replacing opcode 0x1c at 0x0012

09-28 07:09:29.360: DEBUG/dalvikvm(308): VFY: dead code 0x0014-001a in Lcom/ff/org/Bradford;.onListItemClick (Landroid/widget/ListView;Landroid/view/View;IJ)V

09-28 07:09:29.990: INFO/ActivityManager(59): Displayed activity com.ff.org/.Bradford: 674 ms (total 674 ms)

The applicatiuon code is [here:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3807522/maps-force-closing)

Answer (score 2):

I've solved the problem, very noobish thing to have done but I put the internet permission and maps permission in the application area of the manifest.

If you get this error make sure you place the internet and map permissions in the Activity part of the manifest with the class permission.